# Sparql: Query DBPedia and follow redirects

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api, linked-data

I'm trying to query DBPedia for some animal pictures.

The species I'm querying for is Pan_troglodytes. When one visits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_troglodytes in a browser, one gets redirected to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimpanzee.

I'd like to query for Pan_troglodytes and get the thumbnail that appears in the Chimpanzee page. But my query returns nothing:

```
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT * WHERE { 
  dbpedia:Pan_troglodytes 
  dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract;
  dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the thumbnail for the page to which one is redirected? Any pointers others can provide would be helpful!

Comment: the property to use is `dbo:wikiPageRedirects` and a property path (either `*` for "zero or more steps" or `?` for "zero or one" step via the given property, the former is complete as it follow the transitive closure, but might be slow for other cases): `prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT * WHERE { 
  dbr:Pan_troglodytes dbo:wikiPageRedirects* ?o .
  ?o dbo:abstract ?abstract;
  dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
filter(lang(?abstract) = "en")
}`

Comment: Spectacular! UninformedUser has done it again! If you mark your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it :)